# Smallest value of $|\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}|$ where $b,d\leq 1000$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Here is the problem I was given: If $a, b, c, d$ are positive integers with
both $b \leq 1000$ and $d \leq 1000$ and $\frac{a}{b}$
and c/d
are distinct rational numbers (i.e.
they aren’t equal to each other), what is the closest they can be to each other?
That is, what is the smallest possible value for $$\left|\frac{a}{b}-\frac{c}{d}\right|\;?$$

Whatever your answer, give both an example to show that there really are
two such rational numbers that close to each other and give a justification
why there can’t be two such rationals any closer to each other than that.

What I have: I thought that maybe setting b and d to 1000 would be the best way to make the value small but I don't know.

Comment: wouldn't your intuition be to make $a/b$ and $c/d$ as small as possible?  Wouldn't that $\frac ab = \frac 1{1000}$ and $\frac cd = \frac 1{999}$?

Comment: Note that your expression can always be written as $\frac {|ad-bc|}{bd}$ where $bd≤10^6$.  Since the numerator is a non-zero integer it must be at least $1$ so the theoretical minimum is $\frac 1{10^6}$.

Comment: @lulu but wouldn't $\frac 1{10^6}$ only be possible if $b = d = 1000$.  But if that were the case $\frac {ad - bc}{bd}$ would not be in lowest terms and that value would *not* be possible?

Comment: @fleablood  Oh, your solution is optimal, for sure.  I was just giving a very quick way of showing that it was at least extremely close to the theoretical min.  As you remark, some quick argument is still needed to rule out that one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac ab - \frac cd = \frac  {\frac{da - cb}{\gcd(b,d)}}{\frac {db}{\gcd(b,d)}}$.  The absolute smallest that can be is $\frac 1{{\frac {db}{\gcd(b,d)}}}$ where ${\frac {db}{\gcd(b,d)}}$ is a large as possible.

If $\gcd(b,d) \ge 2$ then   ${\frac {db}{\gcd(b,d)}}\le 500,000$ which may not be optimum.  However if we have $\gcd(b,d)=1$ then  ${\frac {db}{\gcd(b,d)}}=bd$ and it is a matter of finding the largest possible $b$ and $d$ that are relatively prime.

As $\gcd(1000,999) = 1$, then $b = 1000; d=999$ and ${\frac {db}{\gcd(b,d)}}= db = 999,000$ is clearly the largest such value.  Provide we can minimize $|da - cb| = |999a - 1000c|$.

Which... obviously can be minimized to $1$ via $a=c=1$.

So $a = 1; c=1;b = 1000; d=999$ is the smallest. at $|\frac 1{1000} - \frac 1{999}| = \frac 1{999,000}$